# Match two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

The first array is

```
$first = Array(0=>orange; 1=>apple; 2=>grapes)
```

the second array is complex

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fruits] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] =>orange
                            [1] => apple
                        )

                    [1] => grapes
                )

            [price] => 69.0   )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fruits] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>orange
                    [1] => grape
                )

            [price] => 40
        )

}
```

The second array is generated from a previous array search. values was in a loop before. Is it feasible to match the array. if so a hink please. itried several options but fruitless.

Comment: I have no idea why you tagged this with `java`

Comment: It's ok. Tags are so members can find questions they are knowledgeable about and can hopefully answer them. So using proper tags will get you better help.

Comment: Why is orange and apple in a new array but not grape? Out of curiosity

Comment: Also, when you say you want to match the array, do you mean check for differences?

Comment: @William Isted : because orange and apple are found in another array. when converted from xml to array, it results as above. @ Lawrence Cherone. well i want to match both arrays so that i can swap the price.

Comment: i am looking for similarities

Answer (score 0):

```
function findMatches( $query, $arrayOfArrays) {

  $ret = array();
  foreach( $arrayOfArrays as $array) {
    if( matches( $array, $query) ) {
      $ret[] = $array;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}

function matches( $array, $query) {
  foreach( $query as $key => $value) {
    if( !isset( $array[$key]) || $array[$key] != $value) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

$isMatching = findMatches($needleArray, $hayStackArray);
```